# Python & Selenium: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: python, selenium, quora

I'm sort of new to Selenium, so after trying to log into **Quora** website:

```
# gets email and password from json
    with open('config.json') as f:
        login_data = json.load(f)
    email = login_data['email']
    password = login_data['pass']

    email_field_xpath = "//input[@name='email']"
    password_field_xpath = "//input[@name='password']"
    login_button_xpath = "//input[@value='Login']"

    # webdriver's going to wait max 10 seconds for email's field, password field, login button to display
    email_field_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_field_xpath))
    password_field_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_field_xpath))

    email_field_element.clear()
    email_field_element.send_keys(email)
    password_field_element.clear()
    password_field_element.send_keys(password)

    # wait till element is visible before interaction
    login_button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_button_xpath)))
    login_button_element.click()
```

I've got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
>
> File "quora.py", line 39, in log_in
>       email_field_element.clear()
>
> File "/home/annieshlepak/work/QuoraAutomatization/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 92, in clear
>       self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
>   ...
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Answer (score 1):

There are two `input` elements with `name="email"` attribute (you can check it with `len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(email_field_xpath))`)

Try to locate required (the second one) element by index

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(email_field_xpath)[1].clear()
```

or use more specific `XPath`:

```
email_field_xpath = '//div[@class="form_column"]/input[@name="email"]'
```

Comment: @AnnieShlepak As a side note `driver.find_element_by` and `EC.presence_of_element_located` doesn't mean the element is visible, just that it exists in the DOM. You need to use one of the `visibility_of` [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) or the `is_displayed()` function.